# How to create generic that supports both reference and value types without using default(T)

Tags: c#, generics

I'm trying to implement generic Queue based on `Array` as data structure.

```
public class ArrayQueue<T>
{
        public T Dequeue()
        {
            if (Queue[Tail] == null)
                return null;

            T value = Queue[Tail];
            Queue[Tail] = null;
            Tail--;
            if (Tail - Head < Queue.Length / (ResizeCoefficient * 2))
                ResizeQueue(Queue.Length / ResizeCoefficient);
            return value;
        }
...
private T[] Queue;
}
```

As you can see, I'm using null as "empty" cell and not `default(T)`.
That's because if T is int, `default(int) = 0` and 0 can be valid input, not empty value. So T must be reference type or `Nullable`. But i don't want client to bother about it, class should support both `ArrayQueue<int>` and `ArrayQueue<Product>`.

Can you suggest any solution with generic class without constrains and in the same time being able to have `Array` of type that can be `null`?

Comment: For value types how about using Nullable<T> instead of T then you can distinguish between unset and set to default.

Comment: You could use an `object[]` array instead of a `T[]` as your store. Then cast/unbox to get your value back. Horrible, I know.

Comment: @JamesLucas: You mean instead of `ArrayQueue<int>`, use `ArrayQueue<Nullable<int>>`?

Comment: What you're asking for is impossible.  Your `Dequeue` method returns a `T` instance so if `T` is `int` then it's not possible to return `null`.  Either `T` must be a nullable value type or `Dequeue` must return type `Nullable<T>`.  You can't have it both ways.

Comment: yes then everything in the queue becomes a reference type

Comment: In that case i have to define array of some type that can contain both nullable and reference - object[] = IsNullable? T[] : Nullable<T>. I'll try, thx!

Comment: Why does it matter if `default(T)` is a valid value? You should be able to keep track of where your queue's head and tail are without using `null` as some kind of flag. Don't forget that `null` is usually a "valid" value for reference types in collections too.

Comment: Rawling, you're absolutely right, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The value `null` should also be a valid value inside your queue. It should not be used to keep track of your tail.

Try to implement a counter or an index which can tell you how many elements are in the queue or where the tail ends. Using this you can insert and return ANY value, including `null`, `0`, `default(T)`, etc.

Maybe a good idea to look at the code of the [System.Collections.Generic.Queue](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7977ey2c(v=vs.110).aspx).